# How to get Excel-Userform to Foreground above CATIA

Tags: excel, vba, catia

I`m currently working on a small CATScript, that is launching an Excel VBA Userform. Everything works flawless, apart from the fact, that the launched Uesrform is stuck to the background with CATIA blocking the Excel Userform.

What can I do to get the Excel Form to the foreground without actively launching the complete workbook?

'Code in CATScript launching the Excel Macro

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Flori\CATIA_Files\test.xlsm")
objExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
objExcel.Application.Run "Modul1.Run"
```

'Code in Modul1

```
Sub Run()

Material_Form.Show vbModeless

End Sub
```

Expected software would open the Userform with Excel itself running in the background. Userform should be "on top" of CATIA and any other programm running.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/386643-userform-always-top.html

Comment: Thank you very much @jkpieterse ! The helping comment! 
Havent been googling enough i guess.. Thanks a lot!